# Page reload after uploading files using formData

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, multipartform-data

I want to prevent page refresh when I upload files. I tried `@click.prevent` and it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
submitForm() {
  const formData = new FormData()
  const files = this.$refs.fileInput.files
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('files[]', files[i])
  }

  //console.log(this.file)
  axiosIns
    .post('api/tickets/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
      },
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      },
    )
},
```

```html
      <VCol cols="6" sm="12">
        <VFileInput ref="fileInput" show-size multiple label="Upload file" :rules="rules" />
      </VCol>
    </VRow>
  </VContainer>
</VCardText>

<VCardActions>
  <VSpacer />
  <VBtn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="dialog = false, errors = null">
    Close
  </VBtn>
  <VBtn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click.prevent="submitForm()">
    Submit
  </VBtn>
```

Comment: You need to add `@submit.prevent` to the `form` element.

Comment: Please include your template code as well. Though, as @qiqqq says, you should just need to use `@submit.prevent` on the `form`, instead of the click event on a button.

Answer (score 0):

if you use button tag to call your method you should add  type="button" to button tag:

```
<button type="button" @click="submitForm" > send file</button>
```

and if you have form tag you should do this:

```
<form @submit.prevent action="submitForm">

// form body
</form>
```

thats should work

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried this solution but it still reload.

Comment: When I change formData from axios request to any other data it works without reload

Comment: could you pls paste your component here?